# android app returns to login page after relaunch

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am facing issues in relaunch of android app, i;e

When I run my application first activity is login, on login it will navigate to home page.

Suppose if home button is pressed and relaunch application from app-drawer it will again start from login page. But if open it from running list in task manager it will come with login page. How to resolve this issue please help me.

Comment: Add android:noHistory="true" into your manifest.xml under <Activity> tag of Login class

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried so far for our reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this code to your **Login.java** `OnCreate`

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(SessionManager.isLogIn(Login.this))) {

        SessionManager.user_id = SessionManager.isLogIn(Login.this);
        SP = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        SessionManager.user_name = SP.getString("user_name", "");
        SessionManager.user_name = SP.getString("user_pass", "");

        SessionManager.uId = SP.getString("id", "");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, HomePage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Make a java class name it **SessionManager.java**

```
public class SessionManager {

    static Context context;

    public static String PREFS_NAME = "settings";
    static SharedPreferences preferences;

    public static String user_id ="";
    public static String user_name ="";

    public static String user_pass ="";

    public static boolean check = true;


  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      context = getApplicationContext();
      mInstance = this;
  }


  public static String isLogIn(Context context) {
      preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

      user_name = preferences.getString("user_name", "");
      user_pass = preferences.getString("user_pass", "");

      return user_id = preferences.getString("user_id", "");
  }

  public boolean logoutUser(Context context) {
      preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);


      return true;
  }

}
```

Add this code in `onClick` of `LOGIN` in **Login.java**

```
    SP = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editit = SP.edit();
        editit.putString("user_id", user_id);
        editit.putString("user_name", etUsername.getText().toString());
        editit.putString("user_pass", etPassword.getText().toString());

        editit.commit();

        SessionManager.user_id = user_id;
        SessionManager.user_name = etUsername.getText().toString());
        SessionManager.user_pass = etPassword.getText().toString());
```

Make this `Global` in **Login.java**

```
    SharedPreferences SP;
```